# Area of parallelogram 3D vectors

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d

I'm given the following parametrization of a parallelogram

$(x,y,z)=(1,1,1)+s\cdot(2,-1,-1)+t\cdot(-1,3,2),s\in[0,1],t\in[0,1]$

I'm now asked to determine the area of this parallelogram as well the unit normal vector in the middle of the parallelogram.

It's been a while since I've dealt with vectors, so any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Do you remember how the cross product relates to areas?

Comment: I think it's the length of the cross product of the two vectors spanning the parallelogram, but would that mean I have to determine the length of the cross product between (2,-1,-1) and (-1,3,2)?

Comment: That’s it exactly. That will also give you a normal to the parallelogram.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! But what about the vector (1,1,1) does that not play any significant role? And how would I determine the midpoint of the parallelogram?

Comment: The specific location of the vertices doesn’t affect the area, but it does determine where the middle of the parallelogram lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $P=(1,1,1)$ a vertex of the parallelogram. The two adiacent vertices are $Q=(3,0,0)$ (for $s=1$ and $t=0$) and $R=(0,4,3)$ (for $s=0$ and $t=1$). So the two vectors parallel to the two sides of the parallelogram $PQ$ and $PR$ are: $\vec v=Q-P=(2,-1,-1)^T$ and $\vec u=R-P=(-1,3,2)^T$.

Now remeber that the oriented area of a parallelogram is given by the corss product of the vectors parallel to two adiacent sides, so the area is the magnitude of the [formal determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Matrix_notation):
$$ \mathbf{A}=
\det \begin{bmatrix}
\vec i & \vec i & \vec k\\
2&-1&-1\\
-1&3&2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Normalizing this ''vector'' you have a unit vector orthogonal to the parallelogram.

Comment: Wouldn't Q-P = (2,-1,-1) instead of (1,-2,-2)? And how would you compute the determinant? It does not seem square to me?

Comment: @James It’s a formal expression. Expand and compute the determinant as if the vectors in the top row were scalars.

Comment: We already had the sides of the parallelogram from its parameterization, so computing the two vertices seems like unnecessary work for this problem.

Comment: Okay, so it seems to me that the area is sqrt(35) when I compute it. But I'm quite lost when it comes to finding the unit normal vector that lies in the middle of the parallelogram..

Comment: @james: You are right! I have edited to correct my mistakes and to add something. The area is $\sqrt{35}$ and the unit vector orthogonal to the parallelogram is$\vec a=\frac{\vec v \times \vec u}{|\vec v \times \vec u |}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{35}}(1,-3,5)^T$.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I got as well. Now I just need to figure out how to place the unit normal vector in the center of the parallelogram

Comment: The center of the parallelogram is at $P+\frac{1}{2}(\vec v + \vec u)$